# How can I get % Growth from Previous Column in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have this data set ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dOyg_YQq7KwBAUjEZffxq_PtjcmaPIHXLWLWGNtiwD8/edit#gid=0)):

| category | February 2022 | March 2022 | April 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gold | 1457 | 1627 | 1890 |
| Silver | 1962 | 2415 | 3036 |
| Bronze | 5683 | 7520 | 10169 |

I want to show the % growth from each month (which is basically growth from the previous column).

For example:
Under Gold, March_2022 growth is:

> (1627 - 1457)/1457 = 11.67%.

Expected outcome might be like this ([Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dOyg_YQq7KwBAUjEZffxq_PtjcmaPIHXLWLWGNtiwD8/edit#gid=867542714)):

| category | February 2022 | March 2022 | April 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gold | - | 11.67% | 16.16% |
| Silver | - | 23.09% | 25.71% |
| Bronze | - | 32.32% | 35.23% |

How can I do that in Google Data Studio?

I have tried comparison calculation: percent difference from total (for both corresponding and base data) but it doesn't work:

[image: percent_diff_total]

My last option might be to hard code it in query, but I prefer to do that in Google Data Studio.

[Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/30a376bb-54fd-48f3-828d-675262c8d207) report

Answer (score -1):

The [calculated fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below could be used (#1 ensures that values are displayed as NULL while #2 and #3 compare values between each month), setting the **Type** to **Numeric > Percent**; to display NULL values as `-`, select the respective symbol from the **Missing Values** section in the **Style** tab of the [table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044):

### 1) February 2022

```
NULLIF(February 2022 / February 2022, 1)
```

### 2) March 2022

```
(March 2022 / February 2022) - 1
```

### 3) April 2022

```
(April 2022 / March 2022) - 1
```

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/50c7745e-a454-4592-8378-e37b8d674d2e) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ffni7JO_sqIpadeplXqV5FPvxUh4zBJHyoHTR4AxK10/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: 5]